# Data in Oracle apex

Tags: sql, oracle, date, oracle-apex

If I want to take data for today from 00:00 until currently hour how can I do it ???
I have this table

| datetime | hourly | clientchannel | servicename | service_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 13_02_2022 | 9 | ***** | notification | 2 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming that `datetime` column's datatype is `DATE` (should be), then

```
select *
from your_table
where datetime between trunc(sysdate) and trunc(sysdate, 'hh24')
```

because

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss';

Session altered.

SQL> select sysdate as right_now,
  2    trunc(sysdate) as midnight,
  3    trunc(sysdate, 'hh24') this_hour
  4  from dual;

RIGHT_NOW           MIDNIGHT            THIS_HOUR
------------------- ------------------- -------------------
01.03.2022 08:01:20 01.03.2022 00:00:00 01.03.2022 08:00:00

SQL>
```

---

If `datetime`'s datatype is `VARCHAR2` (bad choice), then you should first convert it to date, applying correct format model and hoping that there's no garbage in that column:

```
where to_date(datetime, 'dd_mm_yyyy') between ...
```

Comment: The first method worked finally,I wanna ask u when I put ‘hh24’ without minute it give me little data and when I add it give it to me a lot of data what different between them ???

Comment: "hh24" truncates sysdate to *hour*; "mi" truncates it to *mintue*. As you said you wanted data "until currently hour", I presumed it is hh24 you need. If you wanted to fetch today's data up to this moment, then use `between trunc(sysdate) and sysdate`